# How do I add subtitles to a tableview in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

How can I add text to my subtitles? currently I have a NSArray with a list of names, how do I add subtitles for the names?

```
   lodgeList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:

            @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48",
            @"York Lodge No. 12",
            @"Alberene Lodge No. 277",

             nil];
```

Continues...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.text =[lodgeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

Comment: Little help would be nice... don't just -1 my question

Comment: I'd guess the negative votes are due to the vagueness of the question asked. Perhaps showing the code you have already, and a more thorough explanation of what you're trying to achieve, might help you get better responses. As written, it's really impossible to tell just where your troubles lie -- whether in the tableview setup, or in the data itself.

Comment: I just updated the question with code example. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a standard UITableViewCell, make sure you set the table cell's style to `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` , then set the subtitle text by setting the cell's `detailTextLabel.text` property.

Comment: Thanks VeryVito, would I need to create another NSArray for the subtitles ? or just create the property and add "subtitle.detailTextLable.text = [subtitle.....

Comment: See my comment above. There are many ways this could be done (via separate arrays of strings, for instance, or a single array of dictionaries containing the various strings as keyed objects, etc. Hard to know without knowing what you've got already.)

Comment: Does that help a bit? I want to add subviews to the lodge names.

Comment: Sure. Adding a new NSArray would be the quickest solution (although it could get ungainly if you have to keep adding/editing the list, as you need to ensure both lists stay in sync). You could then set `cell.detailTextLabel.text =[otherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` right under your textLabel.text assignment.

Comment: I see,... well I have like 300+ lodges to add. What would be a better way? Is there anyway I could  add it like this @"lodge 1", subtitle"@"city name",..... Im assuming that I cant.. and that they would need to both be in separate arrays, which would make this a mess to update.

Comment: You COULD use a single array as you suggest, adding the titles and subtitles in pairs, and then accessing the array members as  `cell.textLabel.text =[lodgeList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2)];  cell.textLabel.text =[lodgeList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row * 2 + 1)];`, but if you think there's a chance you'll want to add other properties to each record later (and there ALWAYS will be), I would suggest using an array of NSDictionary objects that store each combination instead, as this would later allow you to add more properties to the list later -- without changing anything else.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help.